# Continously updating label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm fairly new to programming, i'm learning python now since thats what i see myself use the most in the future (aspiring data scientist), so i know there is probably better alternatives to overcome my problem nevertheless..

I'm trying to build a really simple idle game with gui. My problem now is that the label for bank is not updating continously, im trying to use the after() command but im not entirely sure how it works.

this is my bank counter. if i run it and print new_bank in console it works as intended.

```
def test(profile):
new_bank = 0
while True:
    new_bank = new_bank + profile.income_per_second()
    return(new_bank)
```

This is my GUI code, or atleast the parts that affects the label i want to update.

```
user = Savegames.select_user()


def bank(user):
    new_bank = 0
    new_bank = new_bank + Savegames.test(user)
    label1.config(text=new_bank)
 
 
 
def main(user):
   root.after(1000, bank(user))
```

Any input regarding if this is even possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function inside the `after` call need to call itself recursively (through the after method) to create an updating loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `bank(user)` (which will be executed immediately) in `.after(...)` because it expects only the function name:

```py
root.after(1000, bank, user)
```

Also you need to call `.after(...)` again inside `bank()` function so `bank()` will be executed periodically:

```py
new_bank = 0

def bank(user):
    global new_bank
    new_bank += Savegames.test(user)
    label1.config(text=new_bank)
    root.after(1000, bank, user)
```